# How to Update table values with existing method in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am working with Laravel 5.6 with MySql database in My web app.

and I have following function method to add order,

```
public function addOrder()
{
$input = Input::all();

$subscribed= false;
if(isset($input['subscribed']))
{
$subscribed= true;
}
```

and In My system I have table name as vehicles as following,

```
**vehicles table**
id   name   number   adtype
1    car     123       0
2    van     159       0
3    car     258       0
4    lorry   147       0
5    van     298       0
etc..
```

Now I need update above table adtype values from 0 to 1 when click submit button regarding to above addorder function. then how can write code to update code in side above function????

My url as following....

```
http://localhost:8000/myads/1/edit/payment
```

route is,

```
Route::post('add-order', 'PaymentController@addOrder');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a **model** then try the following code:

```
public function addOrder()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $subscribed= false;
    if(isset($input['subscribed'])){
        $subscribed= true;
    }
    $vehicle= App\Vehicles::find($input[id]);
    $vehicle->adtype = $subscribed;
    $vehicle->save();
}
```

If you are using **Query Builder** (`add use DB;`)

```
public function addOrder()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $subscribed= false;
    if(isset($input['subscribed'])){
        $subscribed= true;
    }
    DB::table('vehicles')
            ->where('id', $input[id])
            ->update(['adtype' => $subscribed]);
}
```

You must pass the id of a table row to edit each of them(this is must for any method).